# Flutter displaying video from iOS Gallery

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-video-player

I'm trying to implement the functionality of:

1. Recording a video (it's automatically saved to the apps memory)
2. Moving video file from apps memory to gallery (in this step we also save path to newly created video in gallery)
3. Displaying video from gallery

Steps 1. and 3. are written in Flutter, step 2 was implemented natively in Swift.
For some reason this feature sometimes works and sometimes not. When it doesn't work in step 3. I receive an error `PlatformException(VideoError, Failed to load video: The requested URL was not found on this server., null, null)`.

I've also tried using path retrieved from step 2. to simply create File with it `File(path)` but then I also receive an error that file was not found `(OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)`.

I suspect, that on iOS it's caused by the whole App Sandbox thing is that correct? But if it is, why it sometimes does work and sometimes doesn't? Maybe there is something in my code which I could fix?

For step 1. I use [camera](https://pub.dev/packages/camera) package with basically the same code as in example. Then, after receiving `XFile` I run native iOS code, to save video to gallery and get it's path:

```
override func application(
        _ application: UIApplication,
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
    ) -> Bool {
        let controller : FlutterViewController = window?.rootViewController as! FlutterViewController
        let videoSavingChannel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "app.package.name/camera/video_to_gallery",
                                                      binaryMessenger: controller.binaryMessenger)
        videoSavingChannel.setMethodCallHandler({
            [weak self] (call: FlutterMethodCall, result: @escaping FlutterResult) -> Void in
            // This method is invoked on the UI thread.
            guard call.method == "saveVideoToGallery" else {
                result(FlutterMethodNotImplemented)
                return
            }
            
            let args = call.arguments as? Dictionary<String, Any>
            guard let fileUrl = args?["fileURL"] else {
                result(nil)
                return
            }
            
            self?.saveVideoToGallery(fileURL: fileUrl as! String, result: result)
        })
        
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
        return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    }
    
    func saveVideoToGallery(fileURL: String, result: @escaping FlutterResult) {
        PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
            PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo(atFileURL: URL(fileURLWithPath: fileURL))
        }) { saved, error in
            if saved {
                let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
                fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]
                
                PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .video, options: fetchOptions).firstObject?.getURL { urlFromGallery in
                    guard let absoluteUrl = urlFromGallery?.absoluteString else {
                        result(nil)
                        return
                    }
                    result(absoluteUrl)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

getting a video path:

```
extension PHAsset {
    
    func getURL(completionHandler : @escaping ((_ responseURL : URL?) -> Void)){
        if self.mediaType == .image {
            let options: PHContentEditingInputRequestOptions = PHContentEditingInputRequestOptions()
            options.canHandleAdjustmentData = {(adjustment: PHAdjustmentData) -> Bool in
                return true
            }
            self.requestContentEditingInput(with: options, completionHandler: {(contentEditingInput: PHContentEditingInput?, info: [AnyHashable : Any]) -> Void in
                completionHandler(contentEditingInput!.fullSizeImageURL as URL?)
            })
        } else if self.mediaType == .video {
            let options: PHVideoRequestOptions = PHVideoRequestOptions()
            options.version = .original
            PHImageManager.default().requestAVAsset(forVideo: self, options: options, resultHandler: {(asset: AVAsset?, audioMix: AVAudioMix?, info: [AnyHashable : Any]?) -> Void in
                if let urlAsset = asset as? AVURLAsset {
                    let localVideoUrl: URL = urlAsset.url as URL
                    completionHandler(localVideoUrl)
                } else {
                    completionHandler(nil)
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

And then in flutter to display a video I use [video_player](https://pub.dev/packages/video_player) again with pretty basic implementation:

```
VideoPlayerController controller =
        VideoPlayerController.file(File(_videoPathFromGallery));

    controller.initialize().then((_) {
    //...someStuffHere
    }
```

It's probably more of an iOS question rather than a flutter one.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that I've updated the `video_player` library from `2.4.6` to `2.5.1` and after that it stopped working. After downgrading it back to `2.4.6` it started working again.

I've also found how to make it work on `2.5.1` library. Videos from gallery on iOS have path similar to: `file:///var/mobile/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/IMG_0103.MP4`. To make it work we have to remove `file:///` prefix.